# How to use INSTR with Kohana ORM?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, instr

I need to make changes to some old system made with framework kohana (ver. 3.1.1.1), an input where the user must write at least part of the name and the system must output the results.
Usually I work with PHP where I can do it easily with:

```
INSTR(my_table, 'some value') > 0 OR INSTR(my_other_table, 'some value') > 0
```

I saw some kohana orm syntaxis like:

```
$temp = ORM::factory('table_name')->where('column1','=',$value1)->and_where('column2','=',$value2)->find();
```

But I dont know the syntaxis to achieve my INSTR query using the kohana orm.
Can anybody help me?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = ORM::factory('table_name')->where('column1','=',$value1)->and_where('column2','=',$value2)->find()
```

is a bad practice, create model methods with queries.

use `DB::expr()`:

```
 $expression = DB::expr('COUNT(users.id)');
 $query = DB::update('users')->set(array('login_count' => DB::expr('login_count + 1')))->where('id', '=', $id);
 $users = ORM::factory('user')->where(DB::expr("BINARY `hash`"), '=', $hash)->find();
```